# Is possible to display 4 spaces characters as 2 in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, spaces

I am working for company using 4 spaces to indent codebase,

but I am used to 2 spaces, and it's kinda annoying to get eyes used to switch between such different projects.

Is there some way how to make 4 spaces (on the beginning of lines) to look like 2 ? Without any modification of code.

I am using VS Code editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  A workaround (best practice) would be to replace each 4 spaces with a single TAB, then each user can just customize his own tab display width.